# Power Point Text Data Extraction Using Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have modified a code to get the PPT data but it is giving each word or few words in new line. I want Slide by Slide Data i.e .After each Slide it should go for two break line. How can i modify the code please suggest any changes:

**Ex:**

Slide-1
Data
New Line
New Line
Slide-2
Data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
use XML::Twig;
my @text;

my $file = "BI.pptx";
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->read( $file ) == AZ_OK or die "Unable to open Office file\n";
my @slides = $zip->membersMatching( "ppt/slides/slide.+\.xml" );

for my $i ( 1 .. scalar @slides ) # to sort them.
{
#print "Slide: $i\n"; 
my $content="Slide: $i";
 $content .=  $zip->contents( "ppt/slides/slide${i}.xml");
    my $twig= XML::Twig->new( #keep_encoding=>1,
        twig_handlers => { 'a:t' => \&topicref_processing,
            },
        );
    $twig->parse( $content );
}

sub topicref_processing 
{
    my($twig, $ppttext) = @_;
    push @text, $ppttext->text();
}

use FindBin qw($Bin);
open my $out, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", "$Bin/test_ppt-1.txt" or die "$!";
print {$out} "$_\n" for @text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE)

See the example here: [Using OLE to get text out of Powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678663/using-ole-to-get-text-out-of-powerpoint)

Comment: No, you cannot use the Win32::OLE module in Linux because it uses the Windows API. There's a [workaround](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=430194) though.

Comment: Exactly. Our requirement is to run it on Linux environment. The Coe i mentioned is working fine. I just need to segreggate the Slide by slide data.

Comment: I am getting the texts which are present in the ppt. But all are mixed without slide by slide information.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. `@text` will have the content of each slide at each index. Print a Dumper of @text to see you have desired data there. In your code what is the use of `$twig->parse( $content );`? As after parsing it you didn't do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57730/discussion-between-user2131695-and-chankey-pathak).