# How to open a PowerPoint file with PHP

Tags: php, file, copy, powerpoint

I want to be able to open a PowerPoint file with PHP and copy all the text to a different file.

Is this possible or I need another language to do this?

Comment: What does your server setup look like? What kind of envirnoment will you be running this on, Windows or Unix/Linux?

Comment: My Server run on a Linux enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ppt is a powerpoint presentation file, it won't be easy to nearly impossible to copy the data from it. You'd have to use a .net language and office interop to this efficiently.

Comment: You can use Openoffice Convert to convert a PPT to different, readable format to read from it on a Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

[Can PHP read text from a PowerPoint file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646659/can-php-read-text-from-a-powerpoint-file)