# how to work with .PPT files using PHP?

Tags: php, powerpoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP read text from a PowerPoint file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646659/can-php-read-text-from-a-powerpoint-file)

suggest me a good php library from which i can work with .PPT type files

-Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

[PHPPowerPoint](http://www.phppowerpoint.net) would be my first suggestion, though it only writes (no read capability yet) and currently only supports .pptx