# How to make a viewer for Word & PowerPoint files

Tags: php, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint

I am trying to make a viewer for PPTs and DOCs in PHP. Embeddable viewers is an option but that is not what I am looking for. I want help in finding any libraries which would help me do so. I want the viewer to be able to display the presentation/document on the basis of the link I provide to him.

Comment: Is using an external API option for you? If so, did you try looking at zoho API?

Comment: Ya I tried using it but what I want is an open source viewer which does not give me the option to download the file whereas zoho does

Comment: In case of zoho viewer is it possible to stop the users from downloading the file?

Comment: If i understand it right, U want do some thing like google docs(enable the user to edit his files online ans save his fils online), but only difference would be  without letting the user to download them? - OR - Just show a document of yours to him and let him edit it online preventing download?

Comment: I would not like them to download my files at all. Just a viewer

Answer (score 0):

hmm PHP is not able to display a PDF file to the browser. You can however pull data from the PDF file and then rebuild it using whatever format you want.

look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

Comment: I do not require pdf at all. pdf can be displayed directly thats not a problem

Comment: sorry should have read the question more carefully, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646659/can-php-read-text-from-a-powerpoint-file