# PHP presentation (.ppt) word count

Tags: php, powerpoint

I'm trying to get an accurate word count in PHP for ppt files. I do it easily for pptx files with the following function:

```
function parsePPT($input_file){
    $zip_handle = new ZipArchive;
    $output_text = "";
    if(true === $zip_handle->open($input_file)){
        $slide_number = 1; //loop through slide files
        while(($xml_index = $zip_handle->locateName("ppt/slides/slide".$slide_number.".xml")) !== false){
            $xml_datas = $zip_handle->getFromIndex($xml_index);
            $xml_handle = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_datas, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $output_text .= strip_tags($xml_handle->saveXML());
            $slide_number++;
        }
        if($slide_number == 1){
            $output_text .="";
        }
        $zip_handle->close();
    }else{
    $output_text .="";
    }
    return $output_text;
}
```

But can't figure out for ppt files as not much results on Google or here...Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe this could help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9103304/5062442

Comment: Have you tried using any libraries like [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP read text from a PowerPoint file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646659/can-php-read-text-from-a-powerpoint-file)

Comment: PPTX files are plain XML. PPT files are a proprietary binary format.

Comment: @miken32 I have read the other thread, not helping much. Thanks anyway