# how can i strip formatting from word document using php

Tags: php

I want to display a word file  and then extract the content and display it in a separate textarea. i want to do away with the formatting as well.

this is what i get when i get the read the text file using php

> ������ÿÿÿÿ�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Running
>   Head: INTERNATIONAL BUSINESS
>   International Business [Name of the
>   writer] [Name of the institution]
>   International Business Question 1
>   Increasing returns to scale (or
>   economies of scale) in production is
>   an indisputable phenomenon
>   characterizing real world production,
>   and, as such, they have long been
>   recognized as a principal source of
>   economic prosperity. Nonetheless, they
>   have never played a major role in

this is the code

```
$fh = fopen($newname, 'r'); 
$contents => fread($fh, filesize($newname));
fclose($fh); unlink($newname); echo
"<br/>"; echo $contents;
```

how can i get rid of all these charecters.

Thanks

Comment: Word documents do not simply contain plain text, they need to be parsed by something that can parse the proprietary .doc format. See [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)

Comment: The .doc format is incredibly complicated (in fact, it's basically a file system in itself). Joel Spolsky (who also co-founded this site) wrote an article on the matter a few years back at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See this question: [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to send the file to client system and they will be able to download it.

```
<?php
$filename = "test.doc";


if(!file_exists($filename) ) {
    die("The file '{$filename}' does not exist.");
}

header("Content-Type; application/msword");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". basename($filename));
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");


readfile($filename);
?>
```