# Is there a way to parse the text out of a Word doc with PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word, ms-office

My client wants me to extract the text out of an MS Word doc from MS Office 97 and forward to 2011 versions. Is there an API for that with PHP, free or commercial?

**EDIT**: Oh man, look at the comments. Yeah, I forgot to include "want this to work on Linux, as in CentOS Linux (like most shared Linux hosting plans)".

Comment: Try reading this post for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php

Comment: You might try http://www.phpdocx.com/.

Comment: And try the [COM class](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php) to open a .doc file.

Comment: Agreed, the COM methods are much, much better.  Let Office do the work for you.

Comment: phpdocx doesn't support DOC files (the older non-xml formats) I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of under linux is to use the Apache POI

http://poi.apache.org/

It's Java, but it's supposed to read and write both the new XML based files, and the older OLE Compound document files.