# Display document files in html

Tags: php, html, document-view

I am working on a job site where job seekers can upload their resume . When editing their profile , I want them to view their previous resume . I used `<iframe>` for this purpose , but instead of displaying the doc file,it shows an option to download . So how can I display their resume (in .doc,.docx and .odt format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's fopen function, however there is a lot of unwanted code within a word doc file. Maybe a quick search could help you with what you want:

[Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)

It would require a lot of effort. best bet is to create a wysiwyg editor instead of an upload that they can copy and paste to

Answer (score 1):

You can't display .doc,.docx and .odt format files on browser. Basically a browser is designed for parsing HTML files only. You can use Flash to display doc inside your browser,

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the src, if you were to embed the source, it stops Adobe Reader or what not, taking over the browser entirely, and actually views it in the window, this should help:

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

I know this is for PDF's but I would assume you can use it for .doc too.