# Reading DOC file in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to read `.doc .docx` file in php. All is working fine. But at last line I'm getting awful characters. Please help me.
Here is code which is developed by someone.

```
    function parseWord($userDoc) 
{
    $fileHandle = fopen($userDoc, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($userDoc));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $outtext = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $outtext .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }
     $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
    return $outtext;
} 

$userDoc = "k.doc";
```

Here is screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php

Comment: Managed to solve this @no_freedom ? I've tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/5534093/1794894 but it resulted in a partial file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DOC files are not [plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text).

Try a library such as [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) ([old CodePlex site](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)).

nb: This answer has been updated multiple times as PHPWord has changed hosting and functionality.

Comment: And .docx is a .zipped package of multiple files

Comment: @Steve-o I want to count all the words from doc file. Is it possible with PHPword?

Comment: ALso, please note that PHPWord is __NOT__ by Microsoft: it's written as a free Open Source library by a group of independent developers and not supported or endorsed by MS in any way

Comment: Note also that PHPWord does now read BIFF format .doc files, as well as OfficeOpenXML .docx files, and a number of other formats as well

Comment: Note also that PHPWord is officially hosted on github now, not on codeplex

Answer (score 15):

You can read .docx files in PHP but you can't read .doc files. Here is the code to read .docx files:

```
function read_file_docx($filename){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

    $zip = zip_open($filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    //echo $content;
    //echo "<hr>";
    //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
$filename = "filepath";// or /var/www/html/file.docx

$content = read_file_docx($filename);
if($content !== false) {

    echo nl2br($content);
}
else {
    echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how to write into that file?

Comment: @user1817444 It is only reading text from doc, How to get the images with it? images as binary data will also works

Answer (score 4):

I am using this function working well for me :) try it

```
function read_doc_file($filename) {
     if(file_exists($filename))
    {
        if(($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) 
        {
           $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);

           // 1 = (ord(n)*1) ; Document has from 0 to 255 characters
           $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );

           // 1 = ((ord(n)-8)*256) ; Document has from 256 to 63743 characters
           $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );

           // 1 = ((ord(n)*256)*256) ; Document has from 63744 to 16775423 characters
           $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );

           // 1 = (((ord(n)*256)*256)*256) ; Document has from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
           $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );

           // Total length of text in the document
           $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);

           $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);

           // simple print character stream without new lines
           //echo $extracted_plaintext;

           // if you want to see your paragraphs in a new line, do this
           return nl2br($extracted_plaintext);
           // need more spacing after each paragraph use another nl2br
        }
    }   
    }
```

Comment: This function works on to read the doc file but I guess only UTF encoded file. Can you please tell me why the other encoding does not work? I tried to read some file using this function and it does not work for all. The only difference I see is the encoding.

Comment: see my answer below for encoding issues

Comment: After half an hour of searching a simple answer to read a doc file. I got this answer finally which solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Decoding in pure PHP never worked for me, so here is my solution :
http://wvware.sourceforge.net/

Install package

```
sudo apt-get install wv elinks
```

Use it in PHP :

```
$output = str_replace('.doc', '.txt', $filename);
shell_exec('/usr/bin/wvText ' . $filename . ' ' . $output);
$text = file_get_contents($output);
# Convert to UTF-8 if needed
if(!mb_detect_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', true))
{
    $text = utf8_encode($text);
}
unlink($output);
```

Comment: thank you so much @hugsbrugs this is the only way to make it work as I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

I also used it but for accents ( and single quotes like ' ) it would put � instead SOo my PDO mySQL didn't like it but I finally figured it out by adding

```
mb_convert_encoding($extracted_plaintext,'UTF-8');
```

So the final version should read:

```
function getRawWordText($filename) {
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        if(($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) {
            $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);
            $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );// 1 = (ord(n)*1) ; Document has from 0 to 255 characters
            $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );// 1 = ((ord(n)-8)*256) ; Document has from 256 to 63743 characters
            $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );// 1 = ((ord(n)*256)*256) ; Document has from 63744 to 16775423 characters
            $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );// 1 = (((ord(n)*256)*256)*256) ; Document has from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
            $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);// Total length of text in the document
            $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);
            $extracted_plaintext = mb_convert_encoding($extracted_plaintext,'UTF-8');
             // if you want to see your paragraphs in a new line, do this
             // return nl2br($extracted_plaintext);
             return ($extracted_plaintext);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

This works fine in a utf8_general_ci mySQL database to read word doc files :)

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

I'm using soffice to convert doc to txt and read txt converted file

```
soffice --convert-to txt test.doc
```

you can see more in [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/?fbclid=IwAR30-8kD6W7fXwnTgiNv7gi3lzehL3M3Q0as1BEt9lYp2N8rxQo67R5-4as)