# Is there any PHP library support for converting from DOCX to DOC file formats? Even better any MSO-X to the original format

Tags: php, powerpoint, converters, docx, xlsx

I'm developing a system where users will be uploading documents. It will only support MS Office files 2003 and earlier so it currently barfs if the user uploads any of the x files (docx, xlsx, pptx).

I've found [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) in  [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167992/convert-doc-file-into-docx-with-php), but this does the exact opposite of what I need and also is still in what looks to be early beta.

Worst case scenario, are there any good libraries for conversion from these same MSO-X formats to PDFs?

Comment: Checkout OpenOffice.org / LibreOffice.org for your conversion needs.

Comment: Unless there is come CL interface for converting with OO, I don't see how that would help. Am I missing something? I would also prefer to not need to run `exec()` if possible, meaning a pure PHP solution.

Comment: Re OO, Google JODConverter

Comment: @Dan: If there would not be a headless binding of the conversion, I would not have recommended it for your PHP needs. But I only can leave some pointers, you need to throw some keywords into google your own as well if you want to learn more.

Comment: @JasonPlutext, *THAT* is very helpful! Thanks! If you want to expand that out into an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Its not pure PHP, but I think the chances of a reasonable solution including that is unlikely.