# Online Doc,Docx viewer in php?

Tags: php, docx, doc

how can view a doc,docx files using php? there is any php or jquery script is available . i need to show job seekers resume by open the document in online

or any function or classes are available . please let me know your suggestions .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358637/reading-doc-file-in-php see this link

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the contents from docx and doc files and can show them in browser, but you can not show it as what you see in microsft word, you need to format it.

ref: http://phpword.com

Or you need to write a browser plugin to identify .docx exetension and show there, as for pdf files.

```
<?php
    function read_file_docx($filename){

        $striped_content = '';
        $content = '';

        if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

        $zip = zip_open($filename);

        if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;


        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

            $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }// end while

        zip_close($zip);

        //echo $content;
        //echo "<hr>";
        //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);     

        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
        $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

        return $striped_content;
    }



    $filename = "customers.docx";

    $content = read_file_docx($filename);
    if($content !== false) {

        echo nl2br($content);   
    }
    else {
        echo 'Couldn\'t find the file. Please check that file.';
    }
```

Comment: Hi prasanth, Unfortunately given your code is not working for both doc, and docx, can you advise me further, thanks for your reply .

Comment: It will work for docx, are you getting any error? Please give your file name in `$filename = "customers.docx";` keep the docx file in same directory as php file or give relative path there. This is a working code worked for me :)

Comment: It can not be blank, becuase something is echoed there, So i guess there are errors, enable your error reporting or check server error logs.