# Display .docx (.doc) on Browser without downloading in php

Tags: php, ms-word, .doc

Is there any alternative way of viewing a file(locally/online) in `PHP`? Since I want to display a `.docx (.doc)` file in my browser but it keeps on downloading it. So anyone who has a code for that? I keep on searching some other source code but no luck. I tried using `Iframe` but still keeps on downloading the file. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php and take a look at this http://phpword.codeplex.com

Comment: it depends on your server and browser setting

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw what should be the setting for that?

Comment: Convert it to pdf and show that.

Comment: Any `code snippet` please?

Comment: @bruchowski I think PHPWord does not allow reading of Word files. You can just use it to create new files from scratch.

Answer (score 13):

An easy solution to display almost every type of document in browser using iframe.

> Solution is [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

Just use `iframe` as given below and replace url of document in it.

```
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=ENTER URL OF YOUR DOCUMENT HERE&embedded=true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

By Replacing sample url for `.docx` file, above code becomes.

```
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx&embedded=true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

By Replacing sample url for `.pdf` file, above code becomes.

```
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf&embedded=true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

> Note: Document that you need to display in browser must have **correct
> url** and must be **publicly available**, because Google needs to
> fetch and display document, process fails if document is private and
> you will see **iframe** with **NO PREVIEW AVAILABLE**

Answer (score 3):

I have viewed some MS Office documents on [www.dropbox.com](http://dropbox.com) . I just had a look, the tool used is called [QuickLook Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009672) . It converts docx/doc to pdf and displays the pdf document on the website. But it is an iOS library.

If your documents are public, you could use [Office web viewer](http://blogs.office.com/b/officewebapps/archive/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser.aspx) or [Google Docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer).

I have never used PHP to view Word documents online and have never seen a complete tool for that. But writing a parser is definitely possible, the question is - how much of the formatting do you want to retain?
If losing formatting is acceptable, you could try starting with answers from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706822/online-doc-docx-viewer-in-php) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358637/reading-doc-file-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this thread is closed or what but for google view
this code works prefectly

```
<iframe src='//docs.google.com/gview?url=URLOFDOC.docx&embedded=true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```