# Displaying PDF and other document files in a website

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, ms-office

my question is how can I display a PDF or any office document (such as Office,Excel) document inside a web-page. I am using PHP MySQL to upload the documents to the database, and the documents also open. But, the problem is that the documents get downloaded sometimes instead of being viewed on the web page. This is something I don't want to happen and I want the files to be displayed on the user end even if the user does not have any extension in their browser that displays such files. So basically, what I want is to display the files that are uploaded on MySQL database using PHP. I am using XAMPP on localhost and I want my web application to work locally instead of running on a server. I was previously using  and  tags but they both download the files apparently, which I don't want to happen.

I have tried PDF.js from Mozilla but it displays PDF files only, whereas I want to display other documents such as word and excel files as well. Google Document Viewer can be a solution but I don't know how can I use it on a local server without facing complications such as a static IP and a domain name server.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929920/display-docx-doc-on-browser-without-downloading-in-php

Comment: That is more like a Javascript problem than PHP or Mysql

Comment: Hello, I don't know, I just mentioned the tags which I found suitable. Furthermore, I have already researched a lot before actually posting this question, I've been looking for an answer since 2/3 days and about google docs viewer, maybe I failed to explain that I used it earlier already but it doesn't load the files when I'm using links such as localhost/myWebsite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to convert the word document using [PHP Office](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to PDF then convert PDF to image using [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/imagick)

Comment: Take a look here https://i.imgur.com/UqvlmPn.png
It doesn't mention the extensions such as .doc, .docx or xls,xlsx

Comment: It works for .doc and .docx 

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

Comment: Save as pdf 

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF'); $objWriter->save('helloWorld.pdf');