# Is there a way to read Doc files in PHP similar to Docx?

Tags: php, parsing, document

I am able to extract the text content of a Docx File, I want to do the same for Doc file. I tried using the same code but could not read anything. I guess the reason is "Doc formats are not zipped archives." Here is the code:

```
  function readDocx ($filePath) 
    {


        // Create new ZIP archive

        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $dataFile = 'word/document.xml';
        // Open received archive file
        if (true === $zip->open($filePath)) {
            // If done, search for the data file in the archive
            if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
                // If found, read it to the string
                $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
                // Close archive file
                $zip->close();

                // Load XML from a string
                // Skip errors and warnings

                $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

                $contents = explode('\n',strip_tags($xml->saveXML()));
                $text = '';
                foreach($contents as $i=>$content) {
                    $text .= $contents[$i];
                }
                return $text;
            }
            $zip->close();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Please let me know if there is a way to fetch text content from Doc file.

Comment: No it's not that simple because it's not an XML document but a "Word Binary Document" there are readers out there for PHP which read them but it's the same complexity as reading a PDF. So you would have to use a prebuilt lib. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358637/reading-doc-file-in-php

Comment: It's always nice to google first before posting a question. Most probably you're not first facing such a problem...

Comment: Thank you TiMESPLiNTER would check out some libraries.

Thank you Havelock, I did Google about it and could not find an exact solution. That's why I asked the question. Sometimes even similar questions don't get that visibility and most important when you are in a hurry to nail something, you do such mistakes.

Comment: @MohammedFaizanAnsari please do allow me to disagree. SO questions get a *very good* visibility. Even Google's "auto suggest" shows you that you're not the first to ask such a question ;-)

Comment: @Havelock: I am still clueless, the PHPWord library can only create a word file but not read it. There is no any proper solution or suggestion given anywhere. See nobody just comes and ask already asked questions, I asked because I failed to get a solution.  Please help me if you know the proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I finally got the Answer, so thought I should share it here. I simply used COM Objects:

```
$DocumentPath="C:/xampp/htdocs/abcd.doc";

$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate application object");

$wordDocument = new COM("word.document") or die("Unable to instantiate document object");

$word->Visible = 0;

$wordDocument = $word->Documents->Open($DocumentPath);

$HTMLPath = substr_replace($DocumentPath, 'html', -3, 3);

$wordDocument->SaveAs($HTMLPath, 3);

$wordDocument = null;

$word->Quit();

$word = null;

readfile($HTMLPath);

unlink($HTMLPath);
```

Comment: What a pity this only works on Windows because there's no COM class supported in PHP Ubuntu version. :((((

Comment: @尤川豪 Did you find anything for Ubuntu?

Comment: Not yet ...  :((((((((