# From .rtf to .doc(or docx) in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, rtf, docx, doc

I'm trying to convert a .rtf file to a .doc or .docx file, in PHP. But I wonder if this is even possible in PHP.
Does anybody know if this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenOffice or LibreOffice to do it, from command line:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to <TargetFileExtension>:<NameOfFilter> file_to_convert.xxx
```

or using a C++ library that can be used from PHP, called PUNO: 
http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install software on the server

Answer (score 0):

Have a search for PHP Word libraries:

http://phpword.codeplex.com/

PHPWord is a good place to start, same people that develop PHPExcel.

Comment: PHPWord helped me converting my .doc file to docx. That worked perfectly. But it doesn't look like it can convert a .rtf to .doc or .docx. It does work the other way, you can convert a .doc to .rtf, but that's not what I want :) 
Or did I miss something?

Comment: Can't you just add the strings from the .rtf to the word document and output the file? Rather than straight conversion

Comment: Hmm yeah I think I can try that

Comment: @Ruub You say "PHPWord helped me converting my .doc file to docx." How did you do that? All my research says that PHPWord doesn't support the `.doc` format, only the `.docx` format (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358637).