# Get emails from each docx file in directory using php

Tags: php

**hi, all i am making a job portal in 
which user upload multiple resumes 
which contain emails and phone numbers 
so there is any way to get email from a .docx file using php**

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php.

Answer (score 1):

First u must read the docx file.Please refer this [Reading DOC file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358637/reading-doc-file-in-php)

then using

```
$emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
$match = preg_match($emailReg, $your_text);
```

the matches give you the desired output.

Comment: but how to do with .docx file

Comment: look at the last answer in the above link