# How to fix diamond star ����� issue when reading content from .doc file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two issues in this scenario-

1. When I am reading content from doc then it showing me unwanted character like diamond question mark?
2. I want to know key of value "Q1" by using array_search(),How I can know the key(8) of value Q1 in $lines array?

   ```
   if($_POST['Upload'] == 'Upload')
   {
     $myfile = $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"];

    if(($fh = fopen($myfile,'r')) !== false )
    {
       $line = fread($fh, filesize($myfile));

       $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);

       $ans = '';
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($lines);

       var_dump($lines[8]);
       var_dump(array_search($lines[9],$lines));
       var_dump(array_search("Q1.",$lines)); 
   }
   ```

   }
   [image]

Comment: Is there any way you can change the format of the document to .txt? Like, copy the text and paste it in a .txt file and then use that. The issue is with character encoding. The diamond characters are there because of a byte order mark.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522157/3568847

Comment: using `utf8_encode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php may solve the problem

Comment: Is is a Word document? If so you would need a library to parse it -> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: @ka_lin I tried PHP word but this library is  only used to generate doc file.

Comment: @ihodonald yes It can be possible if I convert my data to .txt. Would you please suggest me how to convert doc to txt in php? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though in the description it says: "A pure PHP library for reading and writing word processing documents"

Comment: Alright let me check it again @ka_lin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)