# Convert string to polish Letters

Tags: php, string, converters

Hello I have convert doc file to only string text. I use this function: [Reading DOC file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522157/6678345):

```
function getRawWordText($filename) {
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        if(($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) {
            $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);
            $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );// 1 = (ord(n)*1) ; Document has from 0 to 255 characters
            $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );// 1 = ((ord(n)-8)*256) ; Document has from 256 to 63743 characters
            $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );// 1 = ((ord(n)*256)*256) ; Document has from 63744 to 16775423 characters
            $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );// 1 = (((ord(n)*256)*256)*256) ; Document has from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
            $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);// Total length of text in the document
            $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);
            $extracted_plaintext = mb_convert_encoding($extracted_plaintext,'UTF-8');
             // if you want to see your paragraphs in a new line, do this
             // return nl2br($extracted_plaintext);
             return ($extracted_plaintext);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

This function return:

> jednoznacznie implikuje poBo|enie

It should be:

> jednoznacznie implikuje położenie

I try convert this string to polish letters:

```
return strtr ($mystring, array (
            'B' => 'ł',
            '|' => 'ż',
            ));
```

But I have return:

> jednoznacznie implikuje po�o�enie

I add (like here: [PHP output showing little black diamonds with a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275448/6678345))

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

now I have this:

> jednoznacznie implikuje po³o¿enie

Comment: Add code that reads documents to the question.

Comment: Try `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Could be useful: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` not work, still this same. @svgrafov I add link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522157/6678345

Comment: @michal your code should be included as text within question body, not as link.

Comment: @svgrafov ok sorry, I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

DOC files are not plain text.

Try a library such as [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) ([old CodePlex site](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)).

nb: This answer has been updated multiple times as PHPWord has changed hosting and functionality.

Comment: You could add just link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358766/6678345

Comment: yes you could find some idea from there