# Lucene Zend, index .doc, .pdf, and various types of files

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, indexing, documents

I would like to know if there is some way to index .doc, .pdf, .xls, .ppt, mp3, etc, files using lucene zend framework.

Thanks a lot, and regards

Answer (score 2):

For Readymade solution (good for do things quickly) see [lucene-silverstripe-plugin.](http://code.google.com/p/lucene-silverstripe-plugin/)

For Crude approach (good if you like to learn the internals),

For PDF see http://www.kapustabrothers.com/2008/01/20/indexing-pdf-documents-with-zend_search_lucene/#.TxbJ5jzhdtM

On similar lines you can also index other files.
For Ms-word (.doc file) see

- [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)
- http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php

Comment: The first link is quite detailed on the tools needed to be installed on the server to convert the various file formats to plain text, which can then be indexed.

Comment: Thanks to answer, will try those tools