# Convert html with image to ms.word

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I have the html code as below:

**file.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <p>this is test</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><img src="../../../wamp/www/html2doc/SGEPP.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**html2doc.php**

```
<?php
        $handle = fopen("doc2html.html","r");
        $contents = '';
                while (!feof($handle)) {
                $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
                }   
                header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2word.doc");
                echo $contents;
?>
```

**The problems:**

when I convert it,I get html2word.doc but I can get only all texts from html file.For the images in html file I can not get it, it is missing images.So I want to get all data from html and images also.How do I fix this?Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: You cannot convert html to a word document in this way. All you are doing is outputting the html file with a .doc extension and word is interpreting it for you. To write a word document including embedded images etc is a non-trivial problem. You might find http://www.phplivedocx.org/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php helpful.

Comment: I would like to add to @mjec comment that you forgot to add `/` at the end of the `img` element 
`<img src="../../../wamp/www/html2doc/SGEPP.jpg"/>` is the correct html

Comment: If you can use Java, then you can use docx4j to convert XHTML to docx.

Answer (score 3):

I deal with this script (html2doc) a week ago.
So notice that u dont save images inside `*.doc` file. They are inserted only like links to your server. So solution is to write absolute path in `src` tag.
U read line-by-line your HTML page. So try to find in each line your img tag and replace src with new one.

```
$handle = fopen("html2doc.html","r");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $str = fread($handle, 8192);
    $str = str_replace('src="../../../','src="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/path/to/imgages/',$str);
    $contents .= $str;
}   
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2word.doc");
echo $contents;



// Output:
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<p>this is test</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><img src="http://www.temp.com/path/to/imgages/wamp/www/html2doc/SGEPP.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So now images have path, which MS Word can read well and display images. But remember:
1. u need internet connection to display image
2. deleting (or unavailable server) image will make them unavailable in all generated documents
3. there is no image in doc file included

Comment: Is there no way to insert an image to the word document? I tried to base64 encode the image here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308421/why-cant-my-php-generated-word-document-be-opened but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Generally, header() function only redirect and force to download specific application but word file with images does not work properly it just read from source not a permanent doc file...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a random query after `.jpg` or `.png` like for example : 
`example.com/photo.jpg?ts=12345`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Word support data uri, you may convert your image into base64.

```
// A few settings
$image = 'cricci.jpg';

// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="', $src, '">';
```