# How can i read .doc file from server via php and show the text of .doc file in android app?

Tags: php, android, parsing

I've a word (.doc) file in my server, that's location something like(...../mfunction/booklist.doc). so now I'm confused how can i get the text of (.doc) that file in android app's listview. Is it be done via JSON parsing or XML parsing or something others. In which way it will be better to do ? I'm confused about PHP code, how will i manage it? And my idea says it's not like as usual JSON or XML parsing.

I need better explanation and detail,can anyone help me pls by giving any idea or tutorial link about PHP code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) if you can install packages on your envoirenment. Using this and shell_exec(), you should be able to retrieve the contents of a word document.

Also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/265079/473475 - it suggests a solution if you aren't able to install Antiword.