# Using PHP to read msword and find specific elements e.g. numbering and bullets, underline sentence...?

Tags: php, ms-word

I tried to use the PHP code from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)

I tried the below code but it displays only text. How can i find specific element e.g. numbering and bullets, underline sentence...?:

Is there any trick by using chr() function to solve my problem?

```
<?php
function content($file){
$data_array = explode(chr(0x0D),fread(fopen($file, "r"), filesize($file)));
$data_text = "";
foreach($data_array as $data_line){
if (strpos($data_line, chr(0x00) !== false)||(strlen($data_line)==0))
{} else {if(chr(0) || chr(149)) {
              $data_text .="<br /> ";
             $data_text .= preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$data_line);           
       } 
   }        
}
$data_text = str_replace('Responsibilities','<strong>'.Responsibilities.': </strong>',$data_text);
$data_text = str_replace('Requirements','<strong>'.Requirements.': </strong>',$data_text);
return $data_text;
}
$destination = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$destination.= "upload/";
$maxsize = 5120000;
if (isset($_GET['upload'])) {
      if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "$destination/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'])){
      $file = $destination."/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
      $data = content($file);
      echo $data;
        }   
         }
}else{
      echo "<form  enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='index.php?upload'>
            <input name='userfile' type='file'>
            <input value='Upload' name='submit' type='submit'>
            </form>";
      }
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the older .doc format or the newer .docx?

Comment: I tried read .doc, any help?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a way that will preserve the formatting. You will likely need to use COM to save it as html, but of course you have to be on a Windows PHP server.