# using template system in PHP for doc type

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have lots of docx and doc files in a particular folder.

Lets suppose i have tc.doc file in which following is content

**This is certified that student_name S/o father_name  is a student of this school** 
**and have following address**

Now i have a list of students. if i print a document for particular student i need this data in doc file or it may create new file

**This is certified that Rajat S/o Mr. abc s a student of this school** 
**and have following some addresss**

Rajat / abc and some addresss is in database. Can anybody tell me how to handle this?

I don't know where to start

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php