# Parseing Microsoft Office Documents ServerSide

Tags: php, excel, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm currently working on some educational software which requires me to parse `.doc .ppt .xlsx.`  Basically the students will download a file from my server which will encode metadata with their personal information.  They will then go about following the tutorial, then they will upload the MS files to my website.  I need my server (Linux Hosted) to parse the document and check for any mistakes like formatting and spelling errors.

I'm completely new to MS programming, I only have experience in PHP HTML and mobile application development.  If anyone could post some links or explain the steps I need to take to make this a reality I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PHPDocX.
http://www.phpdocx.com/

Sample demos can be found here.
http://www.phpdocx.com/demo

Also this question will help you.
[Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)

Comment: Have you ever done XML parsing with office? It seems like that would be the way to go? Could you offer any help getting the office documents in an XML form then comparing that XML document to the correct version.