# php count words in .doc,.docx with greek characters

Tags: php, unicode, docx, doc

Im building a web app using php and i have to count the words of an uploaded .doc or .docx file.
So far im using the above functions in order to count the words but this code in not working for greek characters

for .doc

```
 public static function docWordCount($file){
  $fileHandle = fopen($file, "r");
  $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($file));   
  $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
  $outtext = "";
  foreach($lines as $thisline)
    {
      $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
      if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
        {
        } else {
          $outtext .= $thisline." ";
        }
    }
   $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
  return str_word_count($outtext);
 }
```

and for .docx:

```
  public static function docxWordCount($file){ 
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($file);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return str_word_count($striped_content);   
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`str_word_count` does not seem to be binary-safe, meaning it does not support UTF-8 characters. Your best-bet is to use `preg_match` to split the text by non-word characters, using the `\P{L}` property. For example, the following regular expression will split your text in every non-letter character:

```
preg_split('/\P{L}/usi', $str, -1, , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for more information

Comment: My problem is not only the word count but also the conversion from doc to text, when i upload a greek doc the $outtext is like this:   Y, dXiJ(x(I_TS1EZBmU/xYy5g/GMGeD3Vqq8K)fw9
xrxwrTZaGy8IjbRcXI

Comment: Word documents are not text files. You need to convert them first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php

Comment: thank you for the help but please read my comment, the code i've posted first converts the .doc to text and then count the words..

Comment: @man_or_astroman Sadly doesn't work with UTF8 non latin words http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28621ab857d77df14638f8ecfbfe19e855ad4822