# How to convert .docx file into .doc file with PHP?

Tags: php, docx, doc, phpword

I want to read the text from a `.docx` file line by line and keep the each line data in an array, since `.docx` is a zipped file i want to convert it into a `.doc` file so that I can read the file using `@fopen($filename, 'r');`.

Below is the code I tried using PHPWord to conver from `.docx` to `.doc` ,

```
<?php
require_once 'phpWord/PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('BasicTable.docx');

// Save File

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

$objWriter->save('BasicTable4.doc');
?>
```

and this creates an erroneous `.doc` file.

Comment: Reading a `.doc` file using `fopen` and then reading line by line will probably not do want you want.

Comment: @Eborbob if it's a .doc file then i can explode the data for every line break.

Comment: If it's a Word document you'll also have a lot of metadata in there, but it sounds like in your use case you have this covered.

Comment: @Eborbob okay then what wud be the solution for this... can i directly read through .docx file using phpWord?

Comment: I've not used PHPWord but I think it can only create files, not read them. If you have MS Word installed on your PHP server you can use it via COM to read / write documents. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php for other methods.

Comment: can't tell for sure but .doc is format is for pre 2007 ms word. from 2007 onwards .docx extension is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the text out of .docx file and save it as a text file then you can use the library **[docx2text](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/#code)**

after converting it to text file you can read the text file line by line and keep each line data in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use PHPWord. ( http://phpword.codeplex.com/ )

It supports docx as well as doc.

Comment: I could not convert .docx file into .doc file with PHPWord. i have given the codes above, plz check.

Comment: @Astinox are you sure that PhpWord supports both docx and doc? As far as I know it doesn't support writing a .doc file (?). And I assume that the more up to date project link would be https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord (the Git version is the currently active version that was started from the codeplex version)