# Html To Doc(Word) Or RTF Format

Tags: .net, asp.net, ms-office, document

What would the best possible way to convert a html page (with css, tables, images etc.) to be converted to word or rtf format. I already know about adding the

```
content-type = application/word
```

header and that's not an option because we need the images embedded in the document so that it can be viewed without an active internet connection.

I need either a free (preferably) or commercial .NET library or a command line utility as I need to do this on a hosted ASP.NET application on a shared server :|.

Comment: The best wy would be to search before posting. It will save our time ;-)

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471262/css-2-1-compliant-html-to-microsoft-word-conversion

Comment: Not an exact dupe; submitted is looking for a .NET solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Word 2003 or 2007 you can convert xhtml documents to Word Xml documents using xslt. If you google for [html to docx xsl](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=3Q1&q=html+to+docx+xsl+&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) you will find many examples of the opposite (converting docx to html) so you might one of those examples as a basis for a conversion. The only challenge would be downloading and embedding the images in the document, but [that is also possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmahugh/archive/2006/12/10/images-in-open-xml-documents.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities for converting HTML to RTF.  These links should get you started:

- [DocFrac](http://www.docfrac.net/), conversion between HTML, RTF and text.  Free, runs on Windows.
- [XHTML2RTF: An HTML to RTF conversion tool based on XSL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx)
- [Writing an RTF to HTML converter](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/10/20/rtf_5F00_html.aspx)

Converting to MS Word .doc is much harder and probably not worthwhile for you.  For the reasons this is such a pain, read [Joel's interesting article on .doc](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html).  If you have to write .doc for some reason, COM interop with MSOffice is probably your best bet.

Comment: I tried DocFrac and it outputted plain text with some garbage.