# Save Ckeditor Text to word with Images

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I am using Ckeditor, and i saved ckeditor text as a word Document, with the following code.

```
string Text = "<html><body>" + CKEditor1.Text + "</body></html>";
        string DownPath = @"c:\Files";

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(DownPath + @"\" + "Filename" + ".Doc"))
            {
                file.Write(Text);
            }
```

Here the text and styles are saved as it is,But if there are any images in Ckeditor text, they are not displayed in the word document.

I have attached a snap of the word Image error .[image: Error]

**Issue**

How can i save ckeditor data to word with Images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1026392/752527 should help you. You can convert your HTML into XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

What your code did there could only create a text-based document, but not really a Word document.

In order to write image data into your document, you will have to use [MS Word Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26729513/786796) class. Just reference the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` .NET library in your project and you will get heaps of related APIs that can be exposed in your code.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26729513/786796), and it might be helpful to you.