# PHP 4 to Microsoft Word

Tags: php, ms-word

I'm working on a server that is using PHP 4.4.9(doesn't use PHP 5 and I can't upgrade)
I need to write a action that will take an existing PHP page and convert it to a similar looking word document.

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Not easily, and definitely not easily in PHP4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS 2.1 compliant HTML to Microsoft Word conversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471262/css-2-1-compliant-html-to-microsoft-word-conversion) - see openoffice/libroffice headless conversion via exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Apparently the only surefire way to convert HTML to DOC under PHP4 would be to use an external tool and call it through [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

---

One option would be to grab HTML output and feed it to a PDF converter. It isn't exactly a Word document but just might do the trick.

For PHP4:

- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
- [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en)
- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: You really should switch to a host that has PHP5. PHP4 hasn't been supported for three years now - no security fixes.