# Use PHP to create a DOC file on a Unix Box based on an HTML webform selection

Tags: php, html, webforms, ms-word, doc

I have an HTML file which contains a webform with multiple questions which have a YES / NO responses.

If the question has a YES answer, I would like a predefined ( per question ) section of text to be written to a DOC file on the server, but only AFTER the submit button has been pressed ( this way, if the user changes their mind and changes an answer form YES to NO, I won't have to re-write the doc ).

When the user has clicked Submit, The file should be presented as a download.

Any Ideas

Comment: By the way, could you show us the HTML file you mentioned?

Comment: sure 
<form method="post" id="qform" name="qform"><label for="employe" class="blue" id="employelabel" name="employedlabel">Were you employed</label><select name="employedlastyear" class="bluebox" id="employed" type="select" ><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select><p><label for="bfits" class="blue" id="bfitslabel" name="bfitslabel"></label><label for="bfits" class="blue" name="bfitslabel">Did you get bfits</label><select name="bfits" class="bluebox" id="bfits" type="select"><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select></p><form></div>

Answer (score 0):

you only have to link your html form to some script (php, jsp, ...) like this

```
<form action="/myscript.php" method="post">
   YOUR FORM
   <input type="submit" value="Send Form">
</form>
```

Then script does the whole work...here are some examples for php:

- [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)
- [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)