# Generating word documents with PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, doc, phpdocx

Do you know any way to generate `doc` and `docx` files with PHP and without COM component? I've tried `PHPWord`, which creates docx files, but these cannot be opened in `OpenOffice` because they cause it to crash. I've also tried `PHPDocx`, but it didn't generate any files at all.

Comment: *(related)* [Create Word Document Using PHP in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

Comment: Also don't give up on PHPDocx. It looks like a decent package

Comment: Don't give up on PHPWord either... there's a lot of work going into it. Not all versions of OO can read docx files either, are you sure that yours does?

Comment: PHPDocx is paid-for though. No chance!

Answer (score 7):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) can generate Docx documents in pure PHP, using the technique of templates.

Simple.

Answer (score 7):

Generating word documents with JS:

I have created a simple open-source library that will replace tags by values.

For example `Hi {name}` with `data={name:"John"}` will be replaced by `Hi John`.

Here it is : https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater

Demo: https://docxtemplater.com/demo

Comment: nice one, mate :)

Answer (score 6):

See here:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php

To quote from the article the most common method:

## Using HTTP Headers

> In this method you need to format the HTML/PHP page using
>   Word-friendly CSS and add header information to your PHP script. Make
>   sure you don't use external style sheets since everything should be in
>   the same file.
>
> As a result user will be prompted to download a file. This file will
>   not be 100% "original" Word document, but it certainly will open in MS
>   Word application. You can use this method both for Unix and Windows
>   environments.

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");    
  echo "<html>";
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
  echo "<body>";
  echo "<b>My first document</b>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: This is garbage. Don't copy and paste that around further. Sending fake HTTP headers along with some HTML output does **not** make it a Word document. It might have tricked browsers into passing it to Word, which implicitly converts it. Newer versions will at least raise a warning. And any business class firewall is likely to block such crude workarounds.

Comment: @mario - note this is some four years old, and also part of the answer on the duplicate link you have marked. I agree with some of your synopsis, however note that `garbage` is likely hyperbole.

Comment: Sorry for the strong wording, btw. But this very code sample was feeding into misinformed newbie questions. Just closed the topic, and clarified it in the primary duplicate instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making my life easier.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned here [PHP Convert Word file to HTML without losing styling and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996527/php-convert-word-file-to-html-without-losing-styling-and-images/27818143#27818143),

The best solution I've found so far is http://www.phplivedocx.org/ . You use it with the Zend framework. Very easy to set up and you get minimal deviation from the actual word format. It generates and converts word docs from/to html (among other formats) very well.