# MS Word Object Model via Javascript: Mail Merge

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ms-word, mailmerge

I am building a website application for a local charity, it is going well, I seem to overcome most challenges, but this is a huge problem I have, and I don't even know if it is possible.

I want the user to be able to click a button and output a Microsoft Word file by mail merging a text file and a prebuilt template (dotx) file, both on the server side.
The text file will only contain one record that has been taken from an mySQL database and generated via PHP.

I know about using XSLT to modify the document file inside the document zip, but I do not have access to the php.ini on the charities server, and anyway it seems a little bit too much considering how simple it is to use create a Macro to Mail Merge.

So I am now thinking of using the Word Object Model, it would have to be via Javascript, but most of the users use either Firefox or Chrome, so would for eg. `var oApplication = new ActiveXObject("Application.Word");` work with those browsers, or could I use simply `= new Object("Application.Word");`?

Also can I confirm that the object in Javascript would then have the same function names and parameters as those in VBA, I have never tried using Word via Javascript, but if it's the same as VBA, then I should be fine.

I am using my localhost for development and the file structure is:

- template\conformation.docx
- template\data.txt

Where data.txt is the PHP generated CSV of the data taken from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX/COM automation (which is required to access `word.application`) is supported in IE only, no other browser supports it in any way.

If it *were* supported you would still not be able to easily interact with the Word files on the server from within the client.

You could generate the file on the server ( [Generating word documents with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153591/generating-word-documents-with-php) ) although to access functionality that's actually built into Word itself (like a mail merge) you would need to programmatically interact with a real instance of Word that's been installed on the server (using PHP/COM/`word.application`) to control it, to avoid this, you would do whatever the mail merge does, manually.

Another alternative would be to have a Word document that contained VBA code that interacted with a PHP web service to generate the output document.

Answer (score 0):

Is a web-service an option for your application?  If so, have a look at Docmosis - you can upload doc templates then send requests with data to do the mail merge outputting the result with various options including MS word.