# HTML Forms into a .doc File

Tags: html, doc, .doc

I am currently making a contract and there's a lot of them. Is it possible to make an HTML Form with all the Names, address and etc. in there to be filled up. And after filling them up it would save into an already formatted .doc file ready to be printed.

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496677/saving-html-form-data-to-a-doc-file)

Comment: With just html, no. You will need to involve a server side technology here.