# PHP: Any way to populate Word Docs yet?

Tags: php, ms-word, pdf-generation

Last time I worked with PDF generation/.DOC generation in PHP it was awful, and as far as I can tell it's still awful.

I'm wondering if anybody in the community has found a good way (That doesn't involve a paid service) for generating PDFs, or for dynamically filling in values in a Word Document. What I'd like to do now is have the ability for somebody to upload a word document and populate it was PHP

Comment: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what you want to do, but [this class](https://www.php.net/com) might be of assistance. I haven't personally used this though. Might still be awefull.

Answer (score 1):

For pdf, you can opt for [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) or better, with some effort you can even use Apache FOP and here is a similar question on SO [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux). And you can generate doc files as well. The point is you may need to run around. AFAIK, if an open source project, Open Office for example, can generate doc file, you can do that as well.