# Populate microsoft word form field using com object

Tags: php, ms-word

Given a microsoft word with form field, is there some api we can use to populate it? I need to do this at the backend of my php web application.

and, I have seen this link
http://drewd.com/2007/01/25/reading-from-a-word-document-with-com-in-php

Is there a way to field up a form using the word com object?

Comment: Possible (likely) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344007/fill-in-a-microsoft-word-form-with-php

Comment: @ExternalUse question edited, no duplicate now, no one has ever asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<?php
com_load_typelib('Word.Application');
$word = new COM("word.application");
$word->Documents->Open('C:/Doc1.doc');
$word->Visible = 1;
$word->ActiveDocument->FormFields("Text1")->Result = "something";
$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
unset($word);
?>
```

Comment: Hi for the FormFields("Text1"), how do you named the field?

Comment: Well, I suppose you have an existing document. Each Form field in Word has a name. Right-Click the Field -> Properties -> Field settings "Bookmark". Default is Text1, Text2, Textn

Comment: Or loop through in php to check the names - pseudo code: foreach $word->....>FormFields as $field { echo (string) $field->Name }

Comment: Hi, I got error for line $word->Documents->Open('C:/Doc1.doc');, it says  Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference

Comment: Well, have you got a "Doc1.doc" word document in C:\?? You will have to take care of a tiny bit of work yourself... You may want to update your question with the code you are now trying to run.