# Send Word document as an attachment

Tags: php, ms-word, content-disposition

I am creating a Word document dynamically using PHP, and I need to send it as an attachment.

Is there a way to do this that will save it to the server temporarily in order to email it? Is there a better way?

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=giftboxnote.doc");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
...other stuf...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look [on programmershelp](http://www.programmershelp.co.uk/phpcreateword.php) and on Stackoverflow: [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux) and also [there](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/php-create-word-document-t65376.html).