# Can we save ckeditor data into doc file

Tags: php, file

in my site the admin edits some data which i need to save to a doc file. so i implemented this using ckeditor. It works fine but when i try to open this file it says "word cannot start the converter mswrd632.wpc". what am i doing wrong?

```
$content=addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['CKEditor']))
$docfile="convert.doc";
$fp = fopen("files/".$docfile, "w+");
fwrite($fp, $content);
```

this is my code
how can we save data to a doc file.is there any other way?

```
<p class="body">
    England would be keen to finish the summer on a high note by also remaining unbeaten in the upcoming ODI series against world champions India, said Test skipper Andrew Strauss after handing out the visitors a 4-0 whitewash.</p>
```

Comment: What you are doing is not generating a doc file, you are masking a HTML file as a Word file in the hopes that it will auto-import it. Just to clarify. You will probably need to show how your HTML starts

Comment: File types not only differ in their entension. You have to write the data in the doc format, so word can interpret the data. What you saved is basically a usualy text-file.

Comment: so smamatti is there any other way of saving data into doc file

Comment: Just save as `.html`. Word should be able to open that.

Comment: The problem is probably in the HTML. Please show the first few lines of what you are saving

Comment: NO External Stylesheets should be used with the HTML solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. The problem is that the file you are creating is a regular text file with the doc extension, in other words not a real Word file. If you don't have to write a doc file, just keep it as a plain .txt and that will solve the problem.

Now if your project specs require you to have that file as a doc, you can do the following:

1. Use the "HTML" approach(no COM required)
   Take a look at Sergey Kornilov's post: [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

   There is also a similar question here: [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)
2. Use a COM Object - you will have to go that route if you need an elaborate word file

This is from my experience. Let's hope somebody will come up with a better and more efficient solution.

Good Luck!

**UPDATE:**
I automatically assumed you are working in a Win environment. In this case COM will do, if you need it to work on a Linux machine, your alternative is OpenOffice

This is a decent article on COM and stuff: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php#wordcom

For OpenOffice just look at their API - http://api.openoffice.org/
Take a look at their forum, I am sure they have examples  with PHP.

My personal advice is to play with those, but work on a final solution after a day or two, if you have the time. Writing Word files is certainly not my forte, so there could possibly be another way of handling this.

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<body>
<p>England would be keen to finish the summer on a high note by also remaining unbeaten in the upcoming ODI series against world champions India, said Test skipper Andrew Strauss after handing out the visitors a 4-0 whitewash.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dimitar can you elaborate on creating word file using COM object

Comment: Masking HTML code as a .doc file is not necessarily the problem, and can *sometimes* be a viable solution - Word will do its best to convert it. The problem *must* be with the HTML code that is being fed to Word and that the OP is still not showing. Still, your advice is sound and properly building a document is always the best way to go.

Comment: How unfortunate that you have to go that route. I have not done that recently, let me look for a decent article and update my post.

Comment: If the headers are set correctly and HTML has open/close tags there is no reason for Word to not open the file, especially is it is a simple one. I know you probably checked this, but is there anything weird in the data you insert that is not escaped.

Comment: @Dimitar I think he probably did *not* check that :)

Comment: @Sibu If this is all you are saving, I don't think there is any reason to go COM/OpenOffice, just mask it as HTML. This is the data but how are you creating the HTML?