# How to create msword file using php

Tags: php, windows, ms-word

What are available options for creating msword file in windows using php. Do I have to use third party tools or is there some PHP code for that?

Comment: Possbile duplicates: [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux), [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we save ckeditor data into doc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777110/can-we-save-ckeditor-data-into-doc-file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are in fact several options - one nice walkthrough can be found here http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use that class : http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2631-PHP-Create-Microsoft-Word-document-without-COM-objects.html