# How can I convert the content from an HTML Rich Text Editor (Such as CKEditor) into MS Word while retaining CSS formatting?

Tags: html, css, ms-word, ckeditor, doc

Ideally the conversion would be able to handle the inline CSS that the Rich Text Editor would be generating. For example, fonts and text colors, etc. Multiple HTML documents need to be converted into 1 Word document. Currently we are using CKEditor and ASP.Net's ability to save out Word documents by specifying the header parameter, however it is translating very little of the formatting to Word. Is there a 3rd party solution that can provide a more feature rich conversion to Word that retains as much formatting from CKEditor (or another editor) as possible? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we save ckeditor data into doc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777110/can-we-save-ckeditor-data-into-doc-file)