# Save CKEDITOR to word document file

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, docx

How to save CKEDITOR in word document? Is this possible? I reading google 1 day and cannot found the solution. I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
$content=addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['CKEditor']))
$docfile="convert.doc";
$fp = fopen("files/".$docfile, "w+");
fwrite($fp, $content);
```

When i download this file It seems that it is not word document. It is a blank document but it has the contents that I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777110/can-we-save-ckeditor-data-into-doc-file I tried but it doesnt work

Comment: CKEditor produces HTML code which means that to save it as a word document you need to first use HTML to doc converter.