# Yii Framework generating ms-word documents

Tags: yii, frameworks, ms-word

I'm trying to generate a ms-word document with Yii. I'm finding very difficult to do it. I found this example [Generating ms-word](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/16669-exporting-to-ms-word/) but I cannot get it to work.

```
View:
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'Generate Word',
    CController::createUrl('Calculator/generateWord'), array(
        'type'    => 'POST',
    ), array('id'=>'gen_word')
);

Controller:
$var = "hello";
$div = $this->renderPartial('graphs/print', array('var'=>$var), true);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.doc");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $div;

graphs/print:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is just s test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $var; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on the link "Generate Word" it doesn't do anything.

Comment: you can try to use phpword to manipulate word docx document if is not problem the docx file. here is how to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23943396/2327332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction. This is the way it must be done. The problem was that I was doing an Ajax call. Instead by using a simple link there are no problems.

```
View:
echo CHtml::link('Generate Word', array('Calculator/generateWord'));

Controller:
    public function actionGenerateWord() {
    $var = "Hello World!";
    $div = $this->renderPartial('graphs/word', array('var'=>$var), true);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.doc");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $div;
    Yii::app()->end();
}

Rendered view:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is just a test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $var; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```