# How do you open an MS Word file with php?

Tags: php, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

I am trying to open Word files and edit them on linux based operating system.
 
is there any PHP API that enables me to open and edit word file?
I want to read and edit these files and view the images and the text formating.

Comment: There are [many many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+edit+word+document) addressing this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux look here...

Answer (score 0):

We used COM objects to open up MATLAB using PHP on a Windows machine. We were able to control it pretty decently, pass scripts and such. You might want to take a look at that.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757