# PHP print barecode image into word document in php?

Tags: php

Im working on barcode system that will generate 39 barcode image then print it out into a word document, How can i print the resulted image into a word file?

any help?

Comment: no offence...but https://www.google.com.au/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+to+doc

Comment: what solutions did you evaluate so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

Comment: @Jared, no offence, but what Google offered were crappy solutions to the problem. I answered pointing to a better solution. Hopefully Google will index it, and your Google link will become relevant.

Comment: I posted that link to show that the asker could have Google'd it for themself, or even used the search box, as Gordon pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

[PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)

If you don't need an editable final document, use [Zend_PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) instead.

Just consult the API reference of both, both have examples for image embeding.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will see if i can do it soon, but i need it i word document to make changes if needed